# LinkedinApi: get person data by url or name, surname

Tags: linkedin-api

Is there a possibility to get a person's info (name, current job, title, etc.) from the LinkedIn API?

I found a search endpoint(`https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/people/profile-api#public-profile-url`), but it only allows to search by person id, which I have no clue how to get)

`https://api.linkedin.com/v2/people/(id:{person ID})`

I have for a link, for example: `https://www.linkedin.com/in/anton-holovko-7a070476/`

How to get person id according to that link (using the LinkedIn API)?

Answer (score 0):

well i couldnt find the endpoint but i can tell you that all V2 api's of linkedin require you to be a partner with linkedin. so that means you have to accuire a partnership and you have to specify which api's you  are gonna use to get access.

https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs

and normally you get an ID from people that like/comment on a certain post. so if you get posts via the API you also recieve an ID of a person.